# Error when installing Rules with composer

Tags: rules, composer

I've tried to install the latest Rules via composer on drupal 9.3.9. I am new to composer.

I uses "composer require 'drupal/rules:^3.0@alpha'" and got a similar error that on issue https://www.drupal.org/project/rules/issues/3240025

So, I have tried the dev version ("composer require 'drupal/rules:3.x-dev'") and received another error:

Problem 1
- drupal/rules dev-3.x requires drupal/typed_data ^1.0 -> found drupal/typed_data[dev-1.x, 1.0.0-alpha1, ..., 1.x-dev (alias of dev-1.x)] but it does not match your minimum-stability.
- drupal/rules 3.x-dev is an alias of drupal/rules dev-3.x and thus requires it to be installed too.
- Root composer.json requires drupal/rules 3.x-dev -> satisfiable by drupal/rules[3.x-dev (alias of dev-3.x)].

Is the problem with my syntax or settings?

Thx!

Comment: "Should I install Rules via Drupal UI?"  No.  Always use composer; if composer doesn't work, the solution is to fix composer.  The future of Drupal installation/updating is definitely working with composer.

Answer (score 1):

Add or change these in composer.json:

```
minimum-stability: dev,
prefer-stable: true
```